# CompositeView and ItemView, how to handle two views and templates?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following CompositeView(1).
I am wondering what is the best way, for each model of MyCollection, to render two templates and views in order to make something like that(2).

---

(1)

```
var MyCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    template: myTemplate,

    itemView: myView,

    collection: new MyCollection(),

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
        collectionView.$el.find('ul').append(itemView.el);
    }

});
```

---

(2)

```
    appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView1, itemView2) {
        collectionView.$el.find('ul').append(itemView1.el);
        itemView.$el.append(itemView2.el);
    }
```

Comment: Have you made any progress on this since you posted? I'm dealing with a very similar issue -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039722/using-jquery-tabs-with-marionette-layouts

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve your goal, the result should be the same, is to define `onRender funciton` in `Marionette.ItemView`:

Your code in `Marionette.ItemView` should look like this:

```
    onRender: function () {
        var itemView2 = new ItemView2();

        itemView2.render();
        this.$el.append(itemView2.$el);
    }
```

Comment: Does this nullify the need for a composite view? Or is this the itemView that's being called in the composite view? Would there be any way you can show an example?