# Implementing a master view with multiple collections. Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, user-interface

> **EDIT** [my humble mockup](https://moqups.com/AlekseyFilippov/pq8NvmEn) of what I want to implement

---

I have defined such a view:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!_templates/gv_container.html', 'bootstrap/bootstrap-tab'], 
function($, _, Backbone, htmlTemplate, tab) {
    var GridViewContainer = Backbone.View.extend({
        id: 'tab-panel',
        template: _.template(htmlTemplate),
        events: { 'click ul.nav-tabs a': 'tabClicked' },
        tabClicked: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(e.target).tab('show');
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.append(this.template);
            return this;
        }
    });
    return GridViewContainer;
}); // define(...)
```

The view's template looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
    <!-- other tabs -->
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="products">
        <!-- table with rows like { title, few more properties, edit|remove links } -->
    </div>
    <!-- other panes ... -->
</div>
```

Initially I thought I might use it (as common template for all collections at once).

**Goal**

I have three collections: `products`, `categories`, `orders`. And I want to insert each of them as tables on separate `tab-pane`s. As for passing models to `GridViewContainer` I think I can wrap them in a `composite model` and simply pass the latter one as a part of `options` object to `GridViewContainer` view. What's next?

`Product`, `Order`, `Category` models have different properties, have different edit forms and probably event handling. This brings specificity. Should I use `[EntityName]ListView` per collection and then append it to `GridViewContainer` view?

---

> **ASIDE**
>   I use `jquery.js`, `underscore.js`, `backbone.js`, `require.js`, and `ASP.NET MVC 4` on server side.
>   I don't use `Marionette.js`

Comment: I answered a similar question regarding tabbed layouts with backbone here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16066932/693799

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to create a view for each model.
You may create a abstract wich holds the shared stuff like table creation. 
Each view extends your abstract instead of Backbone.View.

```
var myAbstract = Backbone.View.extend({...})
var productsView = myAbstract.extend({...})
```

Then create a view, handling the wrapper (Tabs).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DC7rN/